# Use global variables inside dlls in vb6

Tags: dll, vb6

I have a dll where i would like to access the global variables of the Project.
How can this be done in VB6?

Answer (score 1):

While it is syntactically correct to use a global variable it is a very poor idea. Add either a module or a class file and encapsulate your variable inside a property. If you want to access your properties from within your project a bas file is fine. If you are describing making an ActiveX dll and accessing properties with another, separate project you should make a class module. You will need to set the class **Instancing** property to something other than private.

```
'myproject.bas code
Option Explicit

private mblnIsDirty as boolean

Public Property Let IsDirty(ByVal vIsDirty)

    mblnIsDirty = vIsDirty

End Property
Public Property Get IsDirt() As Boolean

    IsDirty = mblnIsDirty

End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not access anything in a different project unless you explicitly pass it between the projects via COM.